# Style table to have transparent background with opaque text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">  
<tr>
<th>User</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="active">{{player.name|replace("@mysummitps.org","")|replace("@summitsanjose.org","")|replace("@gmail.com","")}}</td>
  <td class="active">{{player.points}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In my CSS I've tried to make the table transparent via:

```
table{
    opacity: 0.3;
     }
```

This obviously makes the entire table transparent. How can I only make the background transparent? I tried changing `background-color:rgba()`, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for any help!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following style:

```
table tr td, table tr th{
    background-color: rgba(210,130,240, 0.3) !important;
}
```

You will need to change the rgb portion to match your colors.  The last argument in the property is the alpha setting which will make the background transparent.

You must also adjust the html to properly place the closing table tag.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">  
<tr>
<th>User</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="active">{{player.name|replace("@mysummitps.org","")|replace("@summitsanjose.org","")|replace("@gmail.com","")}}</td>
  <td class="active">{{player.points}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9LG/

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help as stated in the original post. EDIT: Maybe you meant for me to add this style to another element? I put this in my table{} style.

Comment: Notice I'm using `rgba`.  Also the html markup for the table needs to be adjusted the end tag is directly after the opening tag.

Comment: Oh sorry, I copied it weirdly from my code haha, the tags are fixed. Also, I tried `rgba` and it didn't help either.

Comment: see the updated style.  I'm slightly confused about what you want to achieve, what about the striped style?  Should that be overridden?  Also what about the `tr th` tags?

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped! I removed the `striped`, which I think was messing with the code. I'll accept as correct as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

::: Update - 2023 - BootStrap v5.3 :::

Adding to the above - to get a table with a transparent background, I had to apply a separate class ( in your css file ) as below;

```
.table_custom { --bs-table-bg: transparent !important; }
```

Add this 'table_custom' to the table tag in your code as follows;

```
<table class="table table-sm table_custom">
```

for a table of type small with a transparent background.